# How do I Romance on Renegade for Mass Effect Trilogy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

How do I have a romance on Renegade for Mass Effect Trilogy? For example I can't get a romance with Ashley or Liara on Renegade for Mass Effect 1 or for Mass Effect 3. Also would like to know if you can romance with Traynor on Renegade for Mass Effect 3. Is there really a way to romance on Renegade?

Answer (score 3):

Your alignment in Mass Effect 1 does not stop any of the romances. As long as you are male, you will be able to romance Ashley even if you're renegade.

It's actually quite difficult to lock yourself out of the romances. Talk to the crew member after each mission and don't be a jerk. If you want to stay on the safe side don't pick the bottom option in the conversations.

There are also a few key conversations where you can end the romance and the dialogue if you try to romance both the human option and Liara at once. The answers should be fairly obvious- just let them know you're interested.

It also goes without saying that if you want to romance Ashley,

> You need to save her at the end of Virmire

Traynor is a romance option in Mass Effect 3 but only for a female shepherd.